# When should language tags be used?

Tags: support, tags

I've been spending a lot of time browsing questions under the Ember.js tag. Nearly all of the questions have Javascript as a tag as well, even though the problem is specifically about Ember.js.

Is it OK to remove the Javascript tag if the question only relates to Ember.js and not Javascript?

To me, it just seems like keeping it there would crowd the Javascript tag with questions that most Javascript developers would not be able to answer.

In my opinion, if I click on a tag (like Javascript), I want to see questions with problems related to Javascript, not just questions posted by people who happen to be using Javascript.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't support the removal of the `javascript` tag. It seems to support the removal of `ember.js` on questions where it's not relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I was giving an example from my point of view. I changed Ember.js to Javascript and I think the point is equally relevant.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already [6,538 questions tagged ember.js but not tagged javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js+-javascript?sort=newest&pageSize=50), so it looks like a lot of people already agree that it's ok for the [ember.js](/questions/tagged/ember.js) tag to stand on its own.

A couple of points for comparison:

- This is out of a total of 8,828 questions tagged [ember.js](/questions/tagged/ember.js).
- 26.5% of the [ember.js](/questions/tagged/ember.js) questions *without* the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag are unanswered, which is not significantly worse than the 25.9% overall unanswered rate for the [ember.js](/questions/tagged/ember.js) tag.

I think I agree, the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag doesn't seem to help these questions.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. I think that removing unrelated tags will help clear up some of the noise and speed up the time that it takes for questions to get answered.